# The Android Studio Emulator is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have installed React Native. The Android Studio Emulator is not working. I'm getting the following error. I'm sure I've installed React Native in all its details. I have watched installation videos over and over again. I couldn't solve the problem. Please could you help?

```
PS C:\Users\emrec\Masaüstü\ReactNative\bulutmd> npx react-native run-android
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\emrec\Masaüstü\ReactNative\bulutmd\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\emrec\Masaüstü\ReactNative\bulutmd\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\emrec\Masa�st�\ReactNative\bulutmd\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 413

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\emrec\MasaÃ¼stÃ¼\ReactNative\bulutmd\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 7s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\emrec\Masaüstü\ReactNative\bulutmd\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\emrec\Masaüstü\ReactNative\bulutmd\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\emrec\Masa�st�\ReactNative\bulutmd\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 413

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\emrec\MasaÃ¼stÃ¼\ReactNative\bulutmd\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 7s

    at makeError (C:\Users\emrec\Masaüstü\ReactNative\bulutmd\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\emrec\Masaüstü\ReactNative\bulutmd\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\emrec\Masaüstü\ReactNative\bulutmd\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\emrec\Masaüstü\ReactNative\bulutmd\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
PS C:\Users\emrec\Masaüstü\ReactNative\bulutmd>
```

Answer (score 0):

uninstall @react-native-community library and restart the server

Comment: I installed React Native on my computer. I am sure that I have installed all the steps correctly. I couldn't delete @react-native-community. I've tried all the commands on the Internet.  The problem is the installation (Error: Command failed: gradlew.i think the bat app is:install Debug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081).